# For which real $r$ the Riemann-Liouville operator is bounded in the $L_2[0,1]$ space

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I already proved that for $r > \frac{1}{2}$ the operator is bounded in the $L_2[0,1]$ space.

But I was not able to show the unbounded operator when $r\leq \frac{1}{2}$. My operator looks like this $(Ax)(t) = \frac{1}{t^r}\int_{0}^{t} (t-s)^{r-1}x(s) \,ds$.

I understand that it is necessary to take such a function $x(s)$ that the operator will be unbounded if $r\leq \frac{1}{2}$.But I could not find such a function